# Rails nested route ids don't belong to parent associated id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some nested routes set up like below:-

```
  resources :events, only: :index
  resources :organisations do
    resources :events, except: [:index]
  end
```

The allows me to have the following routes:-

```
/events
/organisations/1/events/1
```

Both of the above work fine, however, I can change the event id in the URL, and it will give me an event that doesn't belong to the organisation, yet the organisation id will remain the same:-

```
/organisations/1/events/2
```

i.e. this will show me Event #2, but the organisation for this event is now Organisation #1.

In my EventsController, I just have the usual generated plain route:-

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :set_organisation, except: %i[index]

  # GET /events/1
  def show; end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
  def set_organisation
    @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:organisation_id])
  end
```

**My question:-** Should Rails know how to handle this and have I set something up incorrectly here, or do I just need to manually handle it by doing a check in my `show` method, that the current event belongs to the current organisation (and redirect somewhere if not)?

Comment: Better to add `set_event` and `set_organisation` methods into description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually handle it.

In set_event `Event.find(params[:id])` finds record directly without any organsaction checks.

One way to handle it is by using scopes. If you pass an event id that does not belong to organisation you will receive RecordNotFound.

```
def set_event
  @event = @organisation.events.find(params[:id])
end
```

Also you need to change order of callbacks: set_organisation should be called before set_event.

Comment: Awesome - thought I'd have to do something like that.  Thanks!